# Set free shipping for base subtotal with discount including tax

Tags: magento2

I need to set free shipping on base subtotal with discount including tax. (i.e. grand total)

I have searched a lot but didn't find any proper link, regarding this.

I am in a very bad situation, I need to know whether this is possible to achieve in magento2 or not.

Answer (score 3):

I think you will achieve this by creating a cart price rule

Login into the admin panel: `Marketing >> Cart Price Rules >> Add New Rule`

Make rule by like below screenshot:

[image]

Hoping this will help you.

Comment: I have created a cart price rule for free shipping, but the issue is subtotal doesn't include tax, I need it on final order total i.e. 'grand total'

Comment: Actually, this is an issue of magneto they are solved in 2.3 develop branch. link https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/12396 & https://github.com/magento/magento2/pull/21288 see both the links you have to update some core file if using the older version of Magento than.

Comment: I have checked these links they are using 'base_subtotal_with_discount', but this does't include tax. 'base_subtotal_with_discount' with 'tax' is only available in 'grand total'